# RuntimeError: Mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (256x65536 and 1024x4096) - Python

Tags: python, matrix, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to use AlexNet to classify spectrogram images generated for 3s audio segments. I am aware that the input image to AlexNet must be 224x224 and have transformed the train and test datasets accordingly. I am encountering the following error: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (256x65536 and 1024x4096 - see link for full error message) and I am not entirely sure why. Can anyone help me figure out where I am going wrong?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnVKp.png

Transform data

```
data_transform_train = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(256),
        transforms.CenterCrop(256),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(norm_mean_train, norm_std_train),
    ])
```

Create dataloaders

```
train_size = int(len(train_data_df))
test_size = int(len(test_data_df))

ins_dataset_train = Audio(
    df=train_data_df[:train_size],
    transform=data_transform_train,
)

ins_dataset_test = Audio(
    df=test_data_df[:test_size],
    transform=data_transform_test,
)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    ins_dataset_train,
    batch_size=256,
    shuffle=True
)

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    ins_dataset_test,
    batch_size=256,
    shuffle=True
)
```

AlexNet Model

```
class AlexNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, output_dim):
        super().__init__()

        self.features = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 64, 3, 2, 1),  # in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),  # kernel_size
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 192, 3, padding=1),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(192, 384, 3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(384, 256, 3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(256, 256, 3, padding=1),
            nn.MaxPool2d(2),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        )

        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Dropout(0.5),
            nn.Linear(256 * 2 * 2, 4096),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Dropout(0.5),
            nn.Linear(4096, 4096),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(4096, output_dim),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.features(x)
        h = x.view(x.shape[0], -1)
        x = self.classifier(h)
        return x, h

output_dim = 2
model = AlexNet(output_dim)

def count_parameters(model):
    return sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad)

print(f'The model has {count_parameters(model):,} trainable parameters')

def initialize_parameters(m):
    if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
        nn.init.kaiming_normal_(m.weight.data, nonlinearity='relu')
        nn.init.constant_(m.bias.data, 0)
    elif isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
        nn.init.xavier_normal_(m.weight.data, gain=nn.init.calculate_gain('relu'))
        nn.init.constant_(m.bias.data, 0)

model.apply(initialize_parameters)
```

Learning Rate Finder

```
class LRFinder:
    
    def __init__(self, model, optimizer, criterion, device):
        
        self.optimizer = optimizer
        self.model = model
        self.criterion = criterion
        self.device = device
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'init_params.pt')

    def range_test(self, iterator, end_lr=10, num_iter=100, smooth_f=0.05, diverge_th=5):

        lrs = []
        losses = []
        best_loss = float('inf')

        lr_scheduler = ExponentialLR(self.optimizer, end_lr, num_iter)
        iterator = IteratorWrapper(iterator)

        for iteration in range(num_iter):

            loss = self._train_batch(iterator)
            lrs.append(lr_scheduler.get_last_lr()[0])
            lr_scheduler.step()

            if iteration > 0:
                loss = smooth_f * loss + (1 - smooth_f) * losses[-1]

            if loss < best_loss:
                best_loss = loss

            losses.append(loss)

            if loss > diverge_th * best_loss:
                print("Stopping early, the loss has diverged")
                break

        model.load_state_dict(torch.load('init_params.pt'))
        return lrs, losses

    def _train_batch(self, iterator):

        self.model.train()
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        x, y = iterator.get_batch()
        x = x.to(self.device)
        y = y.to(self.device)
        y_pred, _ = self.model(x)
        loss = self.criterion(y_pred, y)
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()

        return loss.item()

from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import _LRScheduler

class ExponentialLR(_LRScheduler):
    def __init__(self, optimizer, end_lr, num_iter, last_epoch=-1):
        self.end_lr = end_lr
        self.num_iter = num_iter
        super(ExponentialLR, self).__init__(optimizer, last_epoch)

    def get_lr(self):
        curr_iter = self.last_epoch
        r = curr_iter / self.num_iter
        return [base_lr * (self.end_lr / base_lr) ** r
                for base_lr in self.base_lrs]

class IteratorWrapper:
    
    def __init__(self, iterator):
        self.iterator = iterator
        self._iterator = iter(iterator)

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            inputs, labels = next(self._iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            self._iterator = iter(self.iterator)
            inputs, labels, *_ = next(self._iterator)
        return inputs, labels

    def get_batch(self):
        return next(self)

start_learning_rate = 1e-7
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=start_learning_rate)
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
model = model.to(device)
criterion = criterion.to(device)

END_LR = 10
NUM_ITER = 100[![enter image description here][1]][1]

lr_finder = LRFinder(model, optimizer, criterion, device)
lrs, losses = lr_finder.range_test(train_loader, END_LR, NUM_ITER)
```

Comment: `transforms.CenterCrop(256)` do you mean `transforms.CenterCrop(224)`?

Comment: Maybe you should change to `h = x.view(-1,1024)` in your code?